# How to group by java 8 and collect ids from parent

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, grouping

I have a class A

```
Company {
  String name;
  Logo logo;
}

Logo {
  int color; //can have values=1 (green),2 (red),3 (blue) ...
  String name;
  String address;
}
```

Output needed : for each type 1,2,3 Group all instances of Logo by color. For each such group what were A.id
Give me companies by their color logos.
E.g. which companies have logo red?

I tried following

```
Input
List<Company> company = {//initialization}

company.stream().map(e -> e.getLogo())
          .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(e -> {Logo b = new Logo(); 
                                               b.setType(e.getType(); 
                                               return b;}, Collectors.counting()))
```

This produces a map of Logo and count How do I get names of Company?

Comment: To me your question is unclear! Do you want companies with a red logo? so why do you group them?

Comment: I want companies by each color logo. red = {a, b, c} green = {e, m, g} ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you were to look for all companies given a `color` of their `logo`, you shall group as:

```
Map<Integer, List<Company>> collect = company.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(e -> e.getLogo().getColor()));
```

Just in case, just the count of such values matte, you should then use `Collectors.counting` such as:

```
Map<Integer, Long> count = company.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(e -> e.getLogo().getColor(),
                Collectors.counting()));
```

In short, do not `map` the stream if you want the values to be of type `Company` itself.

**Edit**: Based on comments, if the idea is to convert `Company` to its `name` you can map once grouped. Using `Collectors.mapping` such as :

```
Map<Integer, List<String>> collect = company.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(e -> e.getLogo().getColor(), 
                        Collectors.mapping(Company::getName, Collectors.toList())));
```

Comment: Thanks! This gives me Set<EntrySet<Logo, Company>> How do I convert it to  Set<EntrySet<Logo, String>> String being just the name of companies and not whole company object.

Comment: I can do it by iterating though whole set and collect each value and do getName on it. But I feel, there should be a more concise way.

Comment: * gives me Map<Logo, List<Company>>

Answer (score 1):

You can use `groupingby` collector and then `mapping` collector.

```
companis.stream()
      .collectors(Collectors.groupingBy (c->c.getLogo().getColor(),
  Collectors.mapping (Company::getName,Collectors.toList()));
```